# How to solve Alphametics puzzle using the State Monad and mutable Vector?

Tags: haskell, recursion, monads, backtracking, state-monad

I'm working on the [Alphametics puzzle](https://www.math.uni-bielefeld.de/%7Esillke/PUZZLES/ALPHAMETIC/alphametic-mike-keith.html)

> A set of words is written down in the form of an ordinary "long-hand" addition sum, and it is required that the letters of the alphabet be replaced with decimal digits so that the result is a valid arithmetic sum.Example:

```
SEND
MORE
-----
MONEY
```

This equation has a unique solution:

```
9567
1085
-----
10652
```

A non brute force solution is to use backtracking with memoization. My choice is to use the State Monad along with mutable Vectors.

The algorithm goes as follows:

```
If we are beyond the leftmost digit of the sum:
  Return true if no carry, false otherwise.
  Also check that there is no leading zero in the sum.
Else if addend and current column index is beyond the current row:
  Recur on row beneath this one.

If we are currently trying to assign a char in one of the addends:
  If char already assigned, recur on row beneath this one.
  If not assigned, then:
    For every possible choice among the digits not in use:
      Make that choice and recur on row beneath this one.
        If successful, return true.
        Else, unmake assignment and try another digit.
    Return false if no assignment worked to trigger backtracking.

Else if trying to assign a char in the sum:
  If char already assigned:
    If matches the sum digit, recur on next column to the left with carry.
    Else, return false to trigger backtracking.
  If char unassigned:
    If correct digit already used, return false.
    Else:
      Assign it and recur on next column to the left with carry:
        If successful return true.
        Else, unmake assignment, and return false to trigger backtracking.
```

**I'm having trouble with writing the part where a number is assigned to an addend.**

Rust code for reference that needs to be translated to Haskell.

```
let used: HashSet<&u8> = HashSet::from_iter(solution.values());
let unused: Vec<u8> = (0..=9).filter(|x| !used.contains(x)).collect();
for i in unused {
    if i == 0 && non_zero_letters.contains(&letter) {
        continue;
    }
    solution.insert(letter, i);
    if can_solve(
        equation,
        result,
        non_zero_letters,
        row + 1,
        col,
        carry + (i as u32),
        solution,
    ) {
        return true;
    }
    solution.remove(&letter);
}
false
```

My code, that I've yet to compile, and without the above case implemented, is shown below:

`equation` contains the addend rows.
`result` is the sum row.
`solution` is the assignments.
`nonZeroLetters` is an optimization that checks there are no leading zeros in any of the rows.

```
solve :: String -> Maybe [(Char, Int)]
solve puzzle = error "You need to implement this function."

type Solution = Vector Int

type Row = Vector Char

data PuzzleState = PuzzleState
  { equation :: Vector Row,
    result :: Row,
    nonZeroLetters :: Set Char,
    solution :: MVector Row
  }

canSolve :: Int -> Int -> Int -> State PuzzleState Bool
canSolve row col carry = do
  PuzzleState {equation, result, nonZeroLetters, solution} <- get

  let addend = row < length equation
  let word = if addend then (equation ! row) else result
  let n = length word
  let letter = word ! col

  let ord x = C.ord x - C.ord 'A'
  let readC = UM.read (solution . ord)

  i <- readC letter
  let assigned = i >= 0

  let isNonZero = flip S.member nonZeroLetters

  case () of
    _
      | col >= n && addend -> canSolve (row + 1) col carry
      | col == n && (not . addend) -> carry == 0
      | addend && assigned -> canSolve (row + 1) col (carry + i)

ord :: Char -> Int
ord x = C.ord x - C.ord 'A'

readC ::
  (PrimMonad m, UM.Unbox a) =>
  MV.MVector (PrimState m) a ->
  Char ->
  m a
readC solution c = UM.read solution $ ord c

writeC ::
  (PrimMonad m, UM.Unbox a) =>
  UM.MVector (PrimState m) a ->
  Char ->
  a ->
  m ()
writeC solution c x = UM.write solution $ ord c $ x
```

Here's the (invalid and incomplete) **draft that I need help with**. This is the part for which I showed Rust code above.

```
| addend -> let used <- M.mapM (0 <= UM.read solution) [0..length solution - 1]
                unused = filter (\x -> x == 0 && isNonZero x) [0..9] \\ used
                  in do
                    i <- unused
                    writeC letter
```

**Edit Jan 7, 2023:**

Here's the cleaned up code that produces the compilation error shown at the end.

```
{-# LANGUAGE NamedFieldPuns #-}

module Alphametics (solve) where

import Control.Monad as M
import Control.Monad.Reader (ReaderT)
import qualified Control.Monad.Reader as R
import Control.Monad.ST (ST)
import qualified Control.Monad.ST as ST
import qualified Data.Char as C
import Data.List ((\\))
import Data.Set (Set)
import qualified Data.Set as S
import qualified Data.Vector as V
import qualified Data.Vector.Unboxed as U
import Data.Vector.Unboxed.Mutable (MVector)
import qualified Data.Vector.Unboxed.Mutable as UM

solve :: String -> Maybe [(Char, Int)]
solve puzzle = error "You need to implement this function."

data PuzzleState s = PuzzleState
  { equation :: V.Vector (U.Vector Char),
    result :: U.Vector Char,
    nonZeroLetters :: Set Char,
    solution :: MVector s Int
  }

type M s = ReaderT (PuzzleState s) (ST s)

canSolve :: Int -> Int -> Int -> M s Bool
canSolve row col carry = do
  PuzzleState {equation, result, nonZeroLetters, solution} <- R.ask

  let addend = row < length equation
  let word = if addend then ((V.!) equation row) else result
  let n = length word
  let letter = (U.!) word col
  let x = ord letter
  y <- R.lift $ UM.read solution x
  let assigned = y >= 0
  let isNonZero = flip S.member nonZeroLetters
  let sumDigit = carry `mod` 10

  let used = filter (\i -> 0 <= UM.read solution i) [0 .. length solution - 1]

  case () of
    _
      | col >= n && addend -> canSolve (row + 1) col carry
      | col == n && (not addend) -> return $ carry == 0
      | addend && assigned -> canSolve (row + 1) col (carry + y)
      | addend ->
          let unused = filter (\i -> i == 0 && isNonZero letter) [0 .. 9] \\ used
           in assignAny unused y solution
      | assigned && sumDigit == y -> canSolve 0 (col + 1) (carry `mod` 10)
      | sumDigit `elem` used -> return $ False
      | sumDigit == 0 && isNonZero letter -> return $ False
      | otherwise -> assign 0 (col + 1) (carry `mod` 10) y sumDigit solution
  where
    ord x = C.ord x - C.ord 'A'
    assignAny [] _ _ = return (False)
    assignAny (i : xs) y solution = do
      success <- assign (row + 1) col (carry + i) y i solution
      if success then return (success) else assignAny xs y solution
    assign r c cr y i solution = do
      UM.write solution y i
      success <- canSolve r c cr
      M.when (not success) (UM.write solution y (-1))
      return (success)
```

Error:

```
• Couldn't match type ‘s’
                     with ‘primitive-0.7.3.0:Control.Monad.Primitive.PrimState m0’
      Expected: MVector
                  (primitive-0.7.3.0:Control.Monad.Primitive.PrimState (ST s)) Int
        Actual: MVector
                  (primitive-0.7.3.0:Control.Monad.Primitive.PrimState m0) Int
      ‘s’ is a rigid type variable bound by
        the type signature for:
          canSolve :: forall s. Int -> Int -> Int -> M s Bool
        at src/Alphametics.hs:31:1-41
```

Comment: `State` doesn't have anything to do with mutability. This is a very difficult question to address because it seems confused on critical details and yet to have gone off very far before stopping to check that the starting point was correct. It's hard to say more than that.

Comment: @Carl While I believe my question shows a clear attempt to solving the problem, and also states what is that I’m looking for, I’m afraid your comment is as hand waving as they come. You made some vague reference to critical points but didn’t bother elaborating what you found lacking.

Comment: The critical point is that `State` is unrelated to mutability. Back up and ask questions until you understand that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OP here, figured it out myself. This code, and an alternative implementation using `State` monad, are available [here](https://github.com/asarkar/exercism-haskell/tree/master/alphametics). I’ve done some benchmarking, and surprisingly, the immutable version using `State` appears to be faster than the mutable code below.

```
{-# LANGUAGE NamedFieldPuns #-}
{-# LANGUAGE RecordWildCards #-}

module Alphametics (solve) where

import Control.Monad as M
import Control.Monad.Reader (ReaderT)
import qualified Control.Monad.Reader as R
import Control.Monad.ST (ST)
import qualified Data.Char as C
import Data.List ((\\))
import qualified Data.List as L
import Data.Set (Set)
import qualified Data.Set as S
import qualified Data.Vector as V
import qualified Data.Vector.Unboxed as U
import qualified Data.Vector.Unboxed as VU
import Data.Vector.Unboxed.Mutable (MVector)
import qualified Data.Vector.Unboxed.Mutable as UM

solve :: String -> Maybe [(Char, Int)]
solve puzzle
  -- validate equation, "ABC + DEF == GH" is invalid,
  -- sum isn't wide enough
  | any (\x -> length x > (length . head) res) eqn = Nothing
  | otherwise = findSoln $ VU.create $ do
      let nonZeroLetters = S.fromList nz
      -- process in reverse
      let equation = (V.fromList . map (U.fromList . reverse)) eqn
      let result = (U.fromList . reverse . head) res
      solution <- UM.replicate 26 (-1)
      _ <- R.runReaderT (canSolve 0 0 0) PuzzleState {..}
      return solution
  where
    xs = filter (all C.isAsciiUpper) $ words puzzle
    (eqn, res) = L.splitAt (length xs - 1) xs
    -- leading letters can't be zero
    nz = [head x | x <- xs, length x > 1]
    chr x = C.chr (C.ord 'A' + x)
    findSoln v = case [ (chr x, y)
                        | x <- [0 .. 25],
                          let y = v VU.! x,
                          y >= 0
                      ] of
      [] -> Nothing
      x -> Just x

data PuzzleState s = PuzzleState
  { equation :: V.Vector (U.Vector Char),
    result :: U.Vector Char,
    nonZeroLetters :: Set Char,
    solution :: MVector s Int
  }

type M s = ReaderT (PuzzleState s) (ST s)

canSolve :: Int -> Int -> Int -> M s Bool
canSolve row col carry = do
  PuzzleState {equation, result, nonZeroLetters, solution} <- R.ask

  let addend = row < V.length equation
  let word = if addend then equation V.! row else result
  let n = U.length word

  case () of
    _
      | col >= n && addend -> canSolve (row + 1) col carry
      | col == n && not addend -> return $ carry == 0
      | otherwise -> do
          let letter = word U.! col
          let x = ord letter
          i <- readM solution x
          let assigned = i >= 0
          let canBeZero = flip S.notMember nonZeroLetters
          let sumDigit = carry `mod` 10
          used <- M.mapM (readM solution) [0 .. 25]
          let unused =
                filter
                  (\y -> y > 0 || canBeZero letter)
                  [0 .. 9]
                  \\ used

          case () of
            _
              | addend && assigned -> canSolve (row + 1) col (carry + i)
              | addend -> assignAny solution x unused
              | assigned ->
                  if sumDigit == i
                    then canSolve 0 (col + 1) (carry `div` 10)
                    else return False
              | sumDigit `elem` used -> return False
              | sumDigit == 0 && (not . canBeZero) letter -> return False
              | otherwise ->
                  assign
                    0
                    (col + 1)
                    (carry `div` 10)
                    solution
                    x
                    sumDigit
  where
    -- lift is needed because we're working in in a ReaderT monad,
    -- whereas VM.read and VM.write work in the ST monad
    readM solution = R.lift . UM.read solution
    ord c = C.ord c - C.ord 'A'
    assignAny _ _ [] = return False
    assignAny solution ix (i : xs) = do
      success <- assign (row + 1) col (carry + i) solution ix i
      if success then return success else assignAny solution ix xs
    assign r c cr solution ix i = do
      UM.write solution ix i
      success <- canSolve r c cr
      M.unless success (UM.write solution ix (-1))
      return success
```

Answer (score 4):

There's a larger conceptual problem in your code that's been pointed out in the comments.

The `State` monad simulates a mutable state by passing invisible state values into and out of a sequence of monadic actions.  The state values themselves are immutable, but since they are passed into and out of each action, an action can simulate mutation by returning a state value that's different than the one it was given.

On the other hand, the `Data.Vector` package provides two types of mutable vectors, `IOVector` and `STVector`.  These are vectors with truly mutable elements, not simulated.  They can  be mutated within the `IO` and `ST` monads respectively, because these monads provide the capability for true mutation.  Neither type can be mutated in a `State` monad, because the `State` mutation is only simulated.  It would be too inefficient to implement a third type of mutable vector using `State`'s simulated mutation.

In your program, you are using a `State` that includes a field `solution` with a (true) mutable vector for its value.  This points to a probable design problem.  *Either* you want to simulate mutation with a `State` *or* you want to use a true mutable vector that's made available to your program in some convenient manner, maybe via a `ReaderT`, and manipulated within an `IO` or `ST` base monad.

I actually can't quite understand your `PuzzleState` representation from the code you've provided.  For example, `solution` has type `MVector Row`, which isn't a valid type, but maybe it's supposed to have the unused type `Solution` instead, except that `Solution` isn't mutable.  And I'm not sure what `nonZeroLetters` represents.

However, if your intention is to access fixed character vectors of the addends and result that don't change over the course of solving the puzzle, and mutate an array mapping letters to their digit assignments, then you probably want a "context" that's something like:

```
import qualified Data.Vector as V
import qualified Data.Vector.Unboxed as U
import qualified Data.Vector.Unboxed.Mutable as UM

data PuzzleContext = PuzzleContext
  { equation :: V.Vector (U.Vector Char)   -- fixed matrix of addends, as Chars
  , result :: U.Vector Char                -- fixed result as Chars
  , solution :: UM.IOVector Int            -- mutable array of digit assignments
  }
```

made available using a monad `M` like:

```
import Control.Monad.Reader

type M = ReaderT PuzzleContext IO
```

This allows you to access the puzzle details:

```
canSolve :: ... -> M Bool
canSolve ... = do
    PuzzleContext{equation, result, solution} <- ask
    let c = equation V.! 0 U.! 2  -- access third letter of first addend
```

and mutate the solution:

```
    let ord x = C.ord x - C.ord 'A'
    UM.write solution (ord 'M') 6   -- try M=6
```

Note that `solution` is an immutable *reference* that comes out of the reader, but what it *references* is a mutable vector, which is why you can `UM.write` to its elements within the base IO monad.

As for helping you with your specific draft code, as I say I can't really understand your representation from the code you've written so far, so it's not clear to me how to help with that.

Comment: Thanks for explanation, I see the problem now. Your guess about the addends and result is correct. I’ve updated my question to clarify that. As for the part that I actually need help with, I’ve added a Rust implementation to supplement the steps I listed in my question.

Comment: @k-a-buhr I've updated my code and included the error message that I'm now seeing.